# What is the reason/right situation of using generic pointer in the interface

Tags: c++, api, pointers

What is the reason/right situation of using generic pointer in the interface?
Lots of generic pointers are used in APIs in my company.
For example:

```
void func(void* pData)
{
    MyStruct* pMydata = (Mystruct*)pData;
    //handling pMydata...
}
```

But why don't we just use normal pointer.

```
void func(MyStruct* pData)
{
    //handling pData...
}
```

I think there are few advantage of normal pointer.

1. Decoupling. Caller know exactly what he have to input to this function, without knowing the implement of this function.
2. Compiler will stop caller from inputting incorrect structure, which avoid potential crash/bug.

Of course, some people might say "hey, you can input everything through generic pointer. So you need only one API for all the usecases. Very convenient.".
But I think API who bind everything together, actually mess up everything.
The kind of API is hard to read, maintain, extend.

So....What's the real good timing for using a generic pointer in the interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [usage of void pointer in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124793/usage-of-void-pointer-in-c-c)

Comment: I wouldn't call it "generic". It bypasses the type system - you might as well program in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I check the link you provide and he said "if you don't know what type the data will be you can pass a void*". 
So is there any real example of "I am a callee, I don't know what type caller will pass to me. But I accept whatever caller pass to me."

Comment: It's hard to tell without more context information. Seeing the few lines of code you provided, I'd say it's just poor design.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the purpose of `void*` is type-erasure. In the case of a function argument, this allows passing any type of data into the function.

The use of `void*` is ubiquitous in C, in particular in context of callback functions, where the user of the API can provide custom data to their callback, thereby allowing them to be stateful.

There is rarely a need to use `void*` in C++ API as there are safer alternatives for type-erasure (`std::function` and `std::any` for example), but C API are often used in C++, and therefore defining a function that can be used as such callback is quite typical.

Another use case are functions where input data is going to be reinterpreted as character array, where the implicit conversion into `void*` is preferable to explicit conversion to `char*`. An example of this is `std::memcpy`. Often these functions benefit from a function template wrapper that can be used to enforce some type safety. An example of such is the upcoming `std::bit_cast` which is a wrapper around `std::memcpy`.

Comment: "this allows passing any type of data into the function" - Not *quite*. You cannot pass a pointer to member function through a `void*`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure you can. While `void*` cannot point to a (non-static) member function, it can point to a member function pointer just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you just had this function, then you're right, you should use the actual type `MyStruct*`.

But what if you have another function that takes a function pointer as an argument?

```
void call_function(void (*function)(void *argument), void *argument)
{
    (*function)(argument);
}
```

Then `call_function`'s first argument *must* be a function that takes a `void*`. It cannot be a function that takes a `MyStruct*`.

Usually, we do not write pointless functions like `call_function`, but consider that functions like `pthread_create` (which starts a new thread) have similar arguments to `call_function`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's been mentioned, sometimes C APIs use `void*` for implementation hiding:

```
// --- thing.h ---
// This is your interface, normally in a `.h` file. This is what you distribute
// to your users, together with a (binary) library that they can link against.
// They do not know what "thing" is; they only know that the API allows them to
// do stuff with it.

// Make a thing with some value.
void* make_thing(int value);

// Show the thing.
void show_thing(void* thing);

// Destroy the thing.
void destroy_thing(void** thing);

// --- thing.c ---
// This is your implementation, normally in a `.c` file. You can add whatever
// you want to `thing`; that is completely hidden from the user, who has no
// means to access the internal implementation from within the `.h` file.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct thing {
  int value;
};

// Implement how to actually make a thing.
void* make_thing(int value) {
  struct thing* thing = malloc(sizeof(struct thing));
  thing->value        = value;
  return (void*)(thing);  // This is where you "erase" the type.
}

// Implement how to show a thing.
void show_thing(void* thing) {
  struct thing* actual_thing = (struct thing*)(thing);
  printf("thing->value = %d\n", actual_thing->value);
}

// Implement how to destroy a thing.
void destroy_thing(void** thing) {
  struct thing* actual_thing = (struct thing*)(*thing);
  free(actual_thing);
}

// --- main.c ---
// This is your user's "main" file, where they use your API. They would #include
// "thing.h" and link against some binary `libthing.so` or similar.
int main() {
  // The user can make things and use them, but cannot call any "private" (more
  // precisely "hidden") aspects of its implementation.
  void* thing = make_thing(12);
  show_thing(thing);
  destroy_thing(&thing);
}
```

In practice, good C APIs often use a *opaque* pointers for the same purpose, while providing some sort of type safety. A very neatly-coded example of a good C API is [GLFW](https://github.com/glfw/glfw), which relies on such concept. That is perfectly good C.

In C++ though, such code is smelly. Unless you have to call some third-party API, I see no reason to rely on `void*` or C-style APIs; that's kind of the whole point of C++.